# Async and sync versions of method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, webclient

Ok so I have been reading up a lot and working on the best ways to use `async methods` and `task`, etc.  I believe I'm (mostly) understanding it but I want to check to make sure.

I did start making `async wrappers` for sync tasks using `Task.Run()` but recently read that it's much better to just have a `sync method` and let the application determine if it needs to be pushed to another thread by using `Task.Run()` itself, which makes sense.  However, I've also read that the exception to this is for naturally `async functions`.  I'm not sure I fully understand 'naturally async' but as a basic understanding it seems that .NET framework methods that offer `async methods` are `naturally async` and `WebClient.DownloadFile/DownlodFileAsync` is one of those.

So I have two methods and if anyone would be willing to give feedback I would like to test my understanding and make sure this is correct.

Method one is for moving some files around on the local operating system and looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
Public static void MoveStagingToCache()
{
    ...do some file move, copy, delete operations...
}
```

The second looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
Public static void DownloadToCache()
{
    ...do some analysis to get download locations...
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
    }
    ...do other stuff...
}
```

So my understanding is as follows.  The first method should be left as is, since none of the file operation methods have `async versions` and are therefore not likely naturally `async`.  It would be up to the caller to determine between just calling `MoveStagingToCache()` to run sync or calling `Task.Run(()=>MoveStagingToCache())` to push it to a background thread.

However, in the second method, the download is naturally `async` (unless I misunderstand) so it could create a sync and async version.  In order to do that I should NOT just wrap the sync method like this:

```
Public static Task DownloadToCacheAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>DownloadToCache());
}
```

Instead, I should make the core method async as follows:

```
Public static async Task DownloadToCache()
{
    ...do some analysis to get download locations...
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
    }
    ...do other stuff...
}
```

and then I can create the sync version like this:

```
Public static void DownloadToCache()
{
    DownloadToCacheAsync().Wait();
}
```

This allows for use of the naturally async method and also offers a sync overload for those that need it.

Is that a good understanding of the system or am I messing something up?

Also as an aside, is the difference in `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` and `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync` just that the task returns a task for error catching?

**EDIT**

Ok so after some discussion in the comments and answers I realized I should add some more detail on my system and intended use.  This is inside a library that is intended to be run on desktop, not ASP.  As such, I'm not concerned about saving threads for request processing, the main concern is to keep the UI thread open and responsive to the user and to push 'background' tasks to another thread that can be processed by the system while the user goes about doing what they need to do.

For `MoveStagingToCache`, this will be called on program startup, but I don't need to wait for it to complete to continue loading or using the program.  In most cases it will complete before the rest of the program is up and running and lets the user do anything most likely (probably 5-10 seconds run time max), but even if it's not complete before user interaction starts the program will work fine.  Because of that my main desire here is to move this operation off the UI thread, start it working, and continue on with the program.

So for this one, my current understanding is that this method should be sync in the library, but then when I call it from the main (UI) thread I just use

```
Task.Run(()=>MoveStagingToCache());
```

Since I don't really need to do anything when complete, I really don't need to await this right?  If I just do the above it will start the operation on a background thread?

For `DownloadToCache`, similar but a little different.  I want the user to be able to initiate the download operation, then continue working in the UI until the download is complete.  After it's complete I will need to do some simple operations to notify the user that it's ready to go and enable the 'use it' button, etc.  In this case, my understanding is that I would create this as an async method that awaits the `WebClient` download call.  This would push it off the UI thread for the actual download, but then would return once download is complete to allow me to do whatever UI updates are needed after the await call.

Correct?

Comment: Your understanding is totally correct!

Comment: You probably don't want to block `async` method with `Wait()`: it's not safe. And there's no need to create sync from async.

Comment: I am not aware of the signature of `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` and `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync` however if first method returns void and the second returns task, then you can control your task using second method

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov, It depends. Asp.Net Core does not have Syncronization Context and it does not cause severe blocking issues. I am not sure what you mean by `safe`?

Comment: @Simonare I mean there are chances that the line deadlocks. You're right, in ASP.Net Core there is no unique Synchronization Context _by default_, so it's not a problem, but as far as I understand, nothing prevents someone from creating and setting one. Synchronously blocking on `async` method is still meh though.

Comment: Ok great thank you @Simonare.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov, what if someone wants to run this and wait for it to complete?  I guess they just do that on their own?

Comment: @sfaust they can use producer-consumer pattern, for example `BufferBlock<T>` from `Tasks.Dataflow` or pretty much anything that resembles asynchronous queue. Why look for problems if you can play safe?

Comment: @sfaust so you launch you asynchronous operation and it pushes it's results somewhere at the end, while your synchronous code can block on that "somewhere" and wait for results. Also as you've probably heard, `async` tends to flow "all the way". It is considered a better option to just refactor your code to `async` all the way up the logical call stack.

Comment: Ok thank you.  Not familiar with the BufferBlock or Dataflow, I will look into those.  Thanks all!

Comment: I think it is bad idea to write `DownloadToCache` with a call to `Wait`. If you only implement `DownloadToCacheAsync`, leave it that way. It should be the consumer of your classes to determine how they should call it in sync.

Comment: Added some more comments on my intended use and updated understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked multiple intertwined questions, let me make an attempt to answer most of them, to begin with read articles by [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com) for much more clarity on the working of Async, especially regarding [Naturally Async - There's no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), this will help in understanding what a naturally Async method means.

> **Async Operations**

There are two kind of `Async operations IO bound and CPU bound`

> **How does IO bound Async works**

IO bound are operations which leave the process boundary to make a call to the external service (database, Web Service, Rest API), for which synchronous calls leads to blocking a thread, waiting idle for the out of process call to return, but in case of Async operations calling thread can be released to process other calls.

> **What happens on IO Async call return**

When the call returns, any of the worker thread can be assigned to complete the call, which can be indicated using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on a `Task object`. By virtue of IO bound Async design, system can achieve very high scalability, since the thread, which is a precious / limited resource per process is not wasted in idle waiting.

> **True Async / Natural Async / IO Async**

A True Async request can serve millions of request, compared to few 100 by synchronous system, underlying technology is called as `IO completion ports` in windows. It doesn't need a software thread to process the request, it use the hardware based concurrency

> **CPU Bound Async**

On other hand for the CPU bound async use case is in case of WPF or similar thick clients, which can take background processing on a separate thread, using `Task.Run`, thus free up the Ui thread, keeping system much more responsive, here you don't save a thread, since a worker thread is invoked using `Task.Run`, its all in same process, but system is much more responsive, which is an important achievement via async processing.

> **I did start making async wrappers for sync tasks using Task.Run() but but recently read that it's much better to just have a sync method and let the application determine if it needs to be pushed to another thread by using Task.Run()**

There's no automatic way for the application to decide, its either your code or the code that you are calling which would create a worker thread. For IO bound Async, you need to call the correct API, which would be internally harnessing the Async pipeline exposed by the Windows (IO completion port) to make it pure Async

> **I'm not sure I fully understand 'naturally async' but as a basic understanding it seems that .NET framework methods that offer async methods are naturally async and WebClient.DownloadFile/DownlodFileAsync is one of those.**

Most of the .Net methods offering Async version would be IO bound call, CPU bound need to be explicitly created using `Task.Run` and then awaited. For event based Async implementation `TaskCompletionSource` is a good option, which returns an ongoing awaitable `Task`, which can be `SetResult`, `SetException` for setting the result or error in an event thus asynchronously completing the `Task`. `TaskCompletionSource` is also a threadless implementation

> **Regarding different methods that you have posted**

Your understanding regarding `Method1` is correct, user can decide whether to use a background thread to call it as it free up the main calling thread , which can be a Ui thread. Regarding `Method2`, as it has been mentioned in the comments, make sure it is Async all the way to the top (entry point), as that's the only way to release the calling thread to be utilized in other operations

> **Finally**

This code is very bad idea, also mentioned in the comments by @LexLi

```
Public static Task DownloadToCacheAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>DownloadToCache());
}

Public static void DownloadToCache()
{
    DownloadToCacheAsync().Wait();
}
```

Couple of points:

1. Doing Task.Run on a IO bound Synchronous method, would not have any advantage, since the worker thread is anyway blocked, so a thread is waiting idle unlike Async method, there's no gain in system scalability, since threads are blocked
2. If a method has `Async` version, then it will surely have the `Sync` version, which needs to be used simply `DownloadToCache()`. Sync precedes Async and I am not aware of the case with only Async call but no Sync
3. An explicit `Task.Wait()` is executed in the calling thread, which makes the system un-responsive and can even in few cases lead to deadlock as main thread is blocked, while other operations need to be done on the main / calling thread
4. Only reason for `Task.Wait()` usage is processing some logic on a background / worker / Thread pool thread, which need to be waited and may be use the result before further logical processing, mostly for the CPU bound operations. This is not for the IO bound operations

I hope this helps in providing some clarity regarding the usage of the Async-Await apis

Comment: Hi Mrinal, could you do me a favor? Could you break the single long first sentence from your **Summary** section into smaller, more readable/understandable bites? At 40% of the paragraph, it's a bit difficult to comprehend (for me at least).

Comment: @InteXX check now if it makes more sense

Comment: That's easy to understand, thanks. +1. A question, though... why are those two `DownloadToCache()` calls bad design?

Comment: @InteXX from my understanding basically both of these are creating a misleading method.  In the first, it's not async 'all the way down' so it may not work as expected, and it would be easy for a caller to simply do their own Task.Run if they want it run in a background thread.  In the second, you are blocking the calling thread in a way that could create deadlocks somehow, and again, the caller could easily call wait themselves if they determine that's a good way for their application to work.  Others please correct me if I'm off base anywhere...

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks for the thorough and detailed answer! That helps clarify things significantly and I suspect once I follow a few more of your links it will clarify pretty completely.  I did edit my question to add more details on the intended use cases, etc.

Comment: @InteXX, precisely this part `DownloadToCacheAsync().Wait();` is wrong, since it defeats the purpose of an async call, since it is not able to release the calling thread, as its synchronously waited upon. For a true Async call chain it is `async -await` all the way to the entry point

Answer (score 19):

You [shouldn't write asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), but you also [shouldn't write synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) - these are *both* antipatterns.

Tip: "naturally asynchronous" *mostly* means I/O-based, with a few exceptions. One of those exceptions is some filesystem operations, unfortunately, including moving files, which *should* be asynchronous, but the APIs don't support asynchrony, so we have to pretend it's synchronous.

In your case, `DownloadToCache` is definitely naturally asynchronous. In those cases, I prefer exposing an asynchronous API *only*.

If you must (or *really* want to) support a synchronous API as well, I recommend the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack). The semantic is that if you pass in `sync:true`, then the returned task is already completed. This allows you to keep your logic in a single method and write very small wrappers without the pitfalls normally associated with those wrappers:

```
private static async Task DownloadToCacheAsync(bool sync)
{
  ...do some analysis to get download locations...
  using (var wc = new WebClient())
  {
    if (sync)
      wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
    else
      await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(content.Url), targetPath);
  }
  ...do other stuff...
}
public static Task DownloadToCacheAsync() => DownloadToCacheAsync(sync: false);
public static void DownloadToCache() => DownloadToCacheAsync(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the info.  After thinking about it further it makes sense that those are both anti-patterns, and I guess I don't really have a pressing need to make a sync call so probably better to just provide async but will keep that hack in mind in case I come across a strong need for it.  If you have a chance would you mind reviewing my answer to InteXX in the comments above and make sure I'm not off base?

Comment: I love this pattern thanks! Two questions:

(1) Is it safe to use in ASP.NET given if I'm not using `HttpContext`?

(2) Also, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will still run this on a new threadpool-thread, am I right?

Comment: @Alex: 1) Yes, the bool argument hack is safe to use everywhere. 2) `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` *when used as part of this hack* will just unwrap the result or exception from the task; it doesn't block because the task has completed synchronously.

Comment: @StephenCleary oh, I get it, when `sync==true` the code flow has no `await's` in it, so it will run synchronously.

Comment: I think there should be an `await` in this line: `public static Task DownloadToCacheAsync() => AWAIT DownloadToCacheAsync(sync: false);` I see in the revision history it has been added and removed. Why shouldn't there be an `await` statement at the position I indicate?

Comment: @Stefan no there shouldn't. It's not up to this method to decide, whether to wait or not, the caller will decide.

Comment: @Stefan: See [eliding `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).